# Access denied error while iterating Mysites site collection?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I was iterating current sharepoint site collection for the user which he logged into, and displaying sites names which he has read and contribute permission to sites and this is working fine.
At the same time I have to iterate Mysites site collection where has read and contribute permission. When I do  foreach (SPWeb jweb in esite.AllWebs) in Mysites site collection sub sites. It is throwing an error **"ACCESS DENIED".**

But when I typed url in on browser he can see those sites?. I added code in  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges still unable to access those site. This _layout folder page and I written code in aspx page only.

How to resolve this?

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Web.Site;  // http://committees.test.com
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;  
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{ 
  using (SPSite esite = new SPSite(site.ID))
  {
    Control cont5 = this.LoadControl("/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/ALERTUC/uc5.ascx");
    cont5.ID = "GLOBE";
    RadioButtonList glbrbl = (RadioButtonList)cont5.FindControl("RBList5");

     try
     {
           glbrbl.SelectedValue = user.Notes.ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception) { }
     GlobalPnl.Controls.Add(cont5); 
     foreach (SPWeb jweb in esite.AllWebs)
     {
          if (!jweb.IsRootWeb)
          {
            if (jweb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser().Count != 0)
            {
              if (jweb.ParentWeb.ID == jweb.Site.RootWeb.ID)
              {
                getsubweb(jweb, Panel1, user);
              }
            }
          }
      } 

  }//using        
using (SPSite esite = new SPSite("http://mysitesdev.test.com/groups/grp"))
{
      foreach (SPWeb jweb in esite.AllWebs) //**Access Denied**
      {
          if (!jweb.IsRootWeb)
          {
            if (jweb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser().Count != 0)
            {
              if (jweb.ParentWeb.ID == jweb.Site.RootWeb.ID)
              {
                getsubweb(jweb, Panel1, user);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, RunWithElevatedPrivileges is running in the identity of the Application Pool on `http://committees.test.com`, but is trying to access a site collection on `http://mysitesdev.test.com`. Are both web applications using the same Application Pool identity? Unless the Application Pool identity on `http://committees.test.com` has permissions on `http://mysitesdev.test.com/groups/grp`, I would expect an Access Denied error.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your for each outside the run with elevated privileges, so it is still running in the security context of the user.

Comment: It is still running under security context of the user only.

Comment: try just the last using inside run with elevated privileges

Comment: Thats what I am saying, last using was inside elevated privieges.